# Multiple Securities Trading Algorithm

Tags: algorithmic-trading, portfolio

I am very new to Python and I am having trouble executing my algorithmic trading strategy on more than one security at a time. I am currently using these lines of code for the stocks:

```
data_p = pd.read_csv('AAPL_30m.csv', index_col = 0, parse_dates = True)
data_p.drop(columns = ['Adj Close'])
```

Does anyone know how I would go about properly adding more securities?

Answer (score 0):

Since no data is provided, I can only give you a rough idea on how this can be done. Change directory to the folder with all your data series in csv files:

import pandas as pd
import os

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\username\Downloads\new')
files = os.listdir()
```

Assume the files in the folder is

```
['AAPL.csv',
 'AMZN.csv',
 'GOOG.csv']
```

Then start with an empty dictionary `d` and loop through all the files in the directory to read as pandas dataframe. Eventually combine all of them to one big dataframe (if you find it more useful)

```
d = {}
for f in files:
    name = f.split('.')[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
           ....
    *** Do your processing ***
           ....
    d[name] = df.copy()
    
dff = pd.concat(d)
```

Since I do not know your format and your index, I assume you can do `pd.concat(d)`, alternatively, you may also try out `pd.DataFrame(d)`